# Burned white shadow on 24inch monitor

Tags: display

So I got this brand new monitor today an noticed the following problem:

[image]

This happens while I'm moving my browser window for example.
It's not font related, it also happens with icons as you can see on the picture.
It's only persistend while I'm moving something, the faster I move it, the farther away is the shadow from the origin.

I tested it on windows, linux and two different systems with DVI and VGA.
Is this a known issue ?

**Specifications:**

- Name: Acer S242HLCBID
- 1920x1080 @ 60hz
- 2ms response time
- contrast: 100.000.000:1
- manufacture date: week 48 2011
- LED backlights

Comment: Have you contacted Acer?

Comment: I contacted my reseller first, but I might aswell do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called ghosting, and is either a physical defect in the monitor screen, or sometimes if you're using a poorly-shielded VGA connection with a lot of interference. If you're using a VGA connection, try switching to DVI or HDMI to see if it goes away. If it doesn't, then your best bet is to call up the manufacturer or retail place you bought it (if the purchase was recent enough) and see if they'll replace it.

They may not - Every monitor ghosts on some level, the idea is simply that the pixels can change fast enough that a human won't notice it. It may wind up being subjective over whether the monitor is within operational parameters, or is defective.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like some special case of ghosting for me.  
My old monitor was blurry on movement too, but it didn't look burned in like that. Could it also be GPU related ? My current GPU doesn't support HDMI so I'm using DVI right now.

Comment: It's not a GPU thing. It has to do with the speed at which pixels change colors, specifically that they aren't changing fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

this is a result of the manufacurer trying to overcome the limits of the lcd hardware by overvolting each individual pixel to cheat for better response time/contrast. my suggestion is to return the display, since this cannot be resolved in any other way.

Comment: Mh interesting. I'll update this thread when and if I received a new model. Is there anyway to determine such cheats beforehand ?

Comment: Only by looking at the screen closely in the store before buying... The problem is, that most people don't care anyway.